# Left join if value is NULL, otherwise inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want a join on two tables that replicates left join behaviour if a value is NULL, and inner join behaviour if the value is NOT NULL. For example, for the tables:

```
t1(val) AS (VALUES (NULL)),
t2(val) AS (VALUES ('a'), ('b'))
```

The join would return a single row with values `(NULL,NULL)` (as per a left join). For the tables:

```
t1(val) AS (VALUES ('c')),
t2(val) AS (VALUES ('a'), ('b'))
```

No rows would be returned (as per an inner join). For the tables:

```
t1(val) AS (VALUES ('a')),
t2(val) AS (VALUES ('a'), ('b'))
```

A single row with values `('a','a')` would be returned (as per either type of join).

What is the most efficient way to do this?

EDIT: As part of maximising efficiency, I'm looking for a query that doesn't post-filter (i.e. use the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: What if `t1.val` is *both* `NULL` and not `NULL`?

Comment: I'd probably just use a union where one part checks for null and returns `(NULL,NULL)` and the other part is an inner join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the result would be a union of example 1 AND (2 OR 3), where I say 2 OR 3 depending on whether the value exists in `t2`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
SELECT t1.val, t2.val
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.val = t2.val 
WHERE t1.val IS NULL OR t1.val = t2.val;
```

Or:

```
SELECT NULL AS val1, NULL AS val2
FROM t1 
WHERE val IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.val, t2.val 
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.val = t2.val;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the question to better define maximise efficiency - I'm thinking it should be possible to do this whilst avoiding post-filtering.